# SQL: 4 transfers in different months within the last 6 months and specific words in title in Teradata SQL?

Tags: sql, date, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant, teradatasql

I have table in **Teradata SQL** like below:

[image]

And I need to select only these rows, where:

1. In **title** has (in any configuration, not case sensitive) words: **"cash" or "pay"**
2. Have had at least **4 transfers in different months within the last 6 months** (between 2021-01-03 and 2021-07-03)

So, I need as a result only ID = 111 because this ID has within last 6 months at least 4 title included "cash" or "pay" (in different months)

```
ID
----
111
```

(to put it simply, you have received a salary transfer at least 4 times in the last 6 months -- in diferent month)

I am aware that my sample table is not ideal for this case, because it prestns to small amount of rows, but I believe that description is clear!

I need to do it on **Teradata SQL**, what can I do that ?

To be more precision:

1. Transfer -> is when title has "cash" or "pay" in any configuration, not case sensitive,
2. ID is not unique in table, because some ID can received transfer for example 5 times,
3. Table is constructed that you have payment list of your workers, and you want to find them which received at least 4 transfers in last 6 months (but each transfer in different month)

Comment: What is a transfer?  How are the rows connected?  Is the `id` unique in the table or does it connect different rows?

Comment: 1. Transfer -> is when title has "cash" or "pay" in any configuration, not case sensitive, 2. ID is not unique in table, because some ID can received transfer for example 5 times, 3. Table is constructed that you have payment list of your workers, and you want to find them which received at least 4 transfers in last 6 months (but each transfer in different month)

Comment: Has anyone any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select id
from tab
      -- title has (in any configuration, not case sensitive) words: "cash" or "pay"
where title like any ('%cash%', '%pay%')
      -- last 6 months
  and date between add_months(current_date, -6) and current_date
group by id
       -- at least 4 transfers in different months
having count(distinct trunc(date, 'mon')) >= 4
```

Unless `title` is defined CASESPECIFIC or you run an ANSI-mode session string comparisons are case-insensitive by default.